# White Labeling Provider Advice

Tags: iis, ssl, hosting, branding

I've developed a website that provides a fairly basic service. Users register, fill in online forms, make a payment and then generate some pdf documents based on the data in the forms. They can log in again, downlod documents etc. Nothing amazing...

The sites been developed to change its branding based on a query string parameter (people resell the service as their own). This has been working OK up to now, however more and more people are wanting a full white label service. The good old querystring method isn't transparent enough as users can quite easily see the 'real' domain.

I have thought about looking at the host name rather than the querystring for my branding identifier, easy enough to add a host name under the site in IIS. The issue with this is the site has to run under SSL (1 certificate per IP etc...).

So, whats the best way to achieve this? Can you get multiple domain certificates that aren't all based on the one domain (e.g. extra.test.com & www.simple.co.uk)? I've set up wildcard SSL certs. in IIS before using the old Metabase edit trick, however the wildcard is all one domain.

Is there some proxy tool to will handle the magic? I obviously recode whatever as nessisary, I'm just sure someone must have thought about this already!

Answer (score 1):

Your SSL certs are tied to a single domain. Unless you go with a wildcard cert in which case they're tied to some common root and you can have varying subdomains.

I don't think what you're trying to achieve here is possible.

My suggestion would be that if your customers are demanding their own transparent URLs with SSL, you work that into what you're billing them for the service.

Good luck!

Comment: I had a horrible feeling the first reply would be a "No". Cheers anyway though!